# Python, Windows. Addressing folder in parent directory

Tags: python, windows, directory, cd

I have a **"main" folder with two folders inside: "Data" and "Code"**. "Data" folder contains "limited_scope" folder with .txt files. From "Code" folder I run my_code.py file with lines:

```
import os
directory_path = '..\\Data\\limited_scope\\'
directorie = sorted(os.listdir(directory_path))
```

And get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '..\\Data\\limited_scope\\'
```

When I change to:

```
directory_path = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\main\\Data\\limited_scope\\'
```

the error disappears.

Can anyone tell the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your current working directpry while executing the my_code.py should be the Code directory, then this will work.

Otherwise you can try below code which will use my_code.py's folder and use it:

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
directory_path = os.path.join(current_dir,'..\\Data\\limited_scope\\')
directorie = sorted(os.listdir(directory_path))
```

Comment: It's less confusing if you use the name `script_dir` since it's not necessarily the current directory. Definitely use this approach to access data that's internal to a program. A program doesn't control its initial working directory, which is where the caller wants to load or create files, not where a program looks for its own data files.